Nuxt 3 client middleware executing after page setup
I have a Nuxt app which is entirely front-end (for back-end I use a different app). In it there is a path /user/me.
On the page me.vue there is a component UserSection.
In the UserSection component there is this piece of code:
<script setup>

import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';
import { useAuthenticationStore } from '~/store/authenticationStore';

// Fetch user from the store
const authStore = useAuthenticationStore();
const { authenticatedUser } = storeToRefs(authStore);

console.log("before crash"); // <<< This doesn't even print

// The following line crashes when trying to read authenticatedUser.value.id
const imageUrl = `http://localhost:8080/api/public/user/${authenticatedUser.value.id}/profile-image`

</script>

When I navigate to the page (http://localhost:3000/user/me) directly (not via NuxtLink) I get an error saying that the authenticatedUser.value is null.
I can understand that since this is coming from a store which is not initialized.
To resolve this issue I figured that I should implement a middleware to initialize the store prior to using it in a page:
import { cookieUtils } from "~/lib/api/util";
import { useAuthenticationStore } from "~/store/authenticationStore";

export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async (to, from) => {

  console.log("middleware start"); // <<< This prints after the crash

  if (import.meta.client) {
    const authStore = useAuthenticationStore();
    const authToken = cookieUtils.getAuthToken();
    const authUser = await $fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/protected/user/me", {
      headers: {
        "Auth-Token": authToken
      }
    })
    authStore.updateAuthenticatedUser(authUser);
    authStore.updateAuthenticationToken(authToken);
    authStore.updateAuthenticatedUserID(authUser.id);
  }

  console.log("middleware end"); // <<< This prints after the crash

})

And later use it in the page /user/me.vue like this:
definePageMeta({
  middleware: ["init-authentication-store"]
})

The problem is that the attempt to read authenticatedUser.value.id is happening before the middleware finishes it's job and initializes the store.
What am I missing?
What I want is to make sure that upon every direct page access (not via NuxtLink) the store is initialized and the data is available to the components. If you think there is a better way I'm open to suggestions.
